# Java : Function local variable initialization

Tags: java

I have a java function. In the first function the return variable "ret" is initialized with the declaration in the second function it is initialized inside the try when required. What you guys think which one is better? Please consider List as an example it could be a String and type. Thank you

First Function :

```
public List<String> getNames() {
  List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
       // use ret
  } catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

Second Function :

```
public List<String> getNames() {
  List<String> ret = null;
  try {
       //  some more code
       ret = new ArrayList<String>();
       // use ret
  } catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

Comment: Its not going to make any difference. Because ultimately both statement will execute and your `ret` variable is going to initialized.

Comment: `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`. Negligible difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the two is, if the try block doesn't complete normally, in the first case a blank list will be returned. While in the 2nd case NULL will be returned.

> Which approach is better?

**Depends upon your requirement.**

I usually use the 2nd approach because a blank will still occupy memory.

Having said this, If I assume, that the list will not be filled with the elements outside of `getNames()`, then a blank list occupying memory is not good.

But reverse of this, if the list gets filled with elements outside of `getNames()`, say for example, in the caller method of `getNames()`, then returning a blank list is also ok.

Comment: +1 for memory perspective.

Answer (score 2):

In the first scenario, even if an exception occurs in the try block, you're assured to send a blank `ArrayList`, whereas in the second case, if the exception occurs before the `ArrayList` is initialized, then a `null` would be sent back. Also the good thing about the second approach is that the array list is created only when required and not unnecessarily before.

Either of the approaches is fine, but its better to have the second approach because returning a `null` specifically would mean that some problem had occurred and hence the `null` can handled and interpreted appropriately, whereas a blank `Arraylist` may not always be able to differentiate between an exception and a proper execution with no records being returned.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your objective. Well, if you have some dependencies or condition that must be satisfied before your create the `ArrayList` instance, then you can go for the second option. I would recommend the second option because it creates the instance instantly when needed.The whole decision can be done only when we see the code before you create and use the `ArrayList` instance. This will leave the `List` reference as null when anything failed prior to its creation. We can also make the initialization after the `try catch block` as well

```
public List<String> getNames() {
  List<String> ret = null;
  try {
       // code which is prone to exception
  } catch(Exception e){

  }
   ret = new ArrayList<>();
   //set the values in ret and return it
}
```

}

**Best practice is always initialize the object when only needed.**

Answer (score 0):

The first is better because there is no chance that the assignment of `ret` to `new ArrayList<String>()` will fail. It is good practice to limit the contents of a `try` block to operations which could throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the need.
In the first method, if an exception occurs, you still have control over `ret`, in the latter you dont.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're doing. If you might use ret in both the try and the catch, use the first form. If you only want to use ret in the try block, put the delcaration of ret inside the try block.

```
public List<String> getNames() {
  try {
       //  some more code
       List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
       // use ret
  } catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depend. If there nothing to catch in particular operation. There is no point to put that in a `try-catch`.

```
 List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>(); // here no exception will throw.
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the first method. I don't necessarily see the benefit of initializing it in the `try/catch` although technically you are initializing it by setting it to `null` in that second codeblock before the `try/catch`. To just declare it use `List<String> ret;`.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I have taken a look at this and we think that: initializing List ret within try-catch will ensure any error thown will be caught

Not sure if this is enough for your expectation :)